# Is this code valid under any C standard?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

Does this code follow C standards (e.g. C89, C99, C10x)?

```
void 
main(int a,int b, int c, int d,char *msg){
    if(d==1){
        printf("%s\n",msg);
    }else{
        main(1,2,3,1,&"Hello Stackoverflow");
    }
}
```

If not, why?

Comment: Main should return int, the program is invalid. The argument list is also invalid.  &"string constant" makes no sense. printf is undefined.

Comment: @wildplasser I am pretty sure that `&"literal"` is allowed under C99. Why wouldn't it be any less allowed than `&t` where `t` is an array?

Comment: I did not say it was illegal, I said that it made no sense.

Comment: `&"literal"` has type `const char (*)[8]`, or "pointer to array 8 of `const char`".  This is allowed to be converted to `char*`, but compilers will typically warn about this type of conversion if it lacks a cast (as it does here) since it's often indicative of an error.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, no this is not allowed by the standard. Implicit conversions of pointer types are a constraint violation.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Sorry you're right, I misinterpreted C99 §6.3.2.3/7 "A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different object or incomplete type. [...]".  That condition allows an explicit conversion, but function parameter passing (§6.5.2.2/7) is covered by assignments (§6.5.16.1), and this conversion violates those constraints since `char *` and `const char (*)[8]` are not compatible.

Comment: `C10x` is, in fact `C11`. You can get a [PDF with (a draft of) the C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's one error: `&"Hello Stackoverflow"` does not have type `char*`, so you shouldn't pass that to a function expecting that type.

Apart from that, this program is allowed by the Standard as an implementation-specific extension, but a compiler has the freedom to decline it.

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
>   parameters:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent; **or in some other implementation-defined manner**.

(2011 Standard, latest draft section 5.1.2.2.1, emphasis added.)

There is no ban on recursive calls to `main` in the C Standard. This is a difference with C++, which does outlaw that.

Comment: +1, but the recursive call to `main` has a parameter of wrong type, so this is a constraint violation. The `&` should be omitted.

Comment: Also calling `printf()` (or any function taking a variable number of arguments) without a prototype in scope is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @pmg: I had implicitly assumed `#include <stdio.h>`. Feel free to edit this into the answer, I'm a bit tired (sorry).

Answer (score 2):

You mean beside it won't run?  `main` is defined to take `int, char**` as arguments.

Depending on the compiler, this either will fail to start up as the run-time can't find `main(int, char**)`, or on older compilers it'll just crash because it piddles on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

It's only valid under C99 and later if the implementation *explicitly* documents that `main` may take 5 parameters (4 `int` and 1 `char *`) and return `void` (that's the "or in some other implementation-defined manner" clause that larsmans referenced in his now-un-deleted answer, and I don't think that clause was present in C89).

Otherwise the behavior is undefined, meaning the compiler may or may not choke on it.