# call function using yes or no

Tags: c, loops, return-value, function-calls

I want to convert an amount in *Ringgit Malaysia* to its equivalent value in *USD*. And I want to write a C program that could ask the user to enter *yes* or *no* to continue subsequent function.

I have done some coding

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char y, n, Y, N, ans;
    printf("\nWould you like to continue ?:\t");
    scanf("%c",&ans);

    switch (ans)
    {
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
           convert();
           break;
        case 'N':
        case 'n':
           return(0);
           break;
        default:
            {
                return (0);
            }
            break;
            return 0;
    }

    while (ans==y || ans==Y);
        return main();

}

int convert () {
    float ia,ca;

    printf("\nEnter amount in Ringgit Malaysia : RM ");
    scanf("%f",&ia);

    ca=ia/3.30;

    printf("\nRM %.2f is equals to USD %.2f\n\n\n",ia,ca);

    return main();
}
```

But my output is shown as below

```
Would you like to continue ? : y
Enter amount in Ringgit Malaysia : RM 100
RM 100.00 is equals to USD 30.30


Would you like to continue ? : 
Would you like to continue ? : y
Enter amount in Ringgit Malaysia : RM 100
RM 100.00 is equals to USD 30.30

Would you like to continue ? : 
Would you like to continue ? : n
```

My question is why the question repeat twice?

By the way the output should be like this

```
Would you like to continue ? : y
Enter amount in Ringgit Malaysia : RM 100
RM 100.00 is equals to USD 30.30

Would you like to continue ? : y
Enter amount in Ringgit Malaysia : RM 100
RM 100.00 is equals to USD 30.30

Would you like to continue ? : n
```

Comment: Why do you recursively call `main()`? just fun?

Comment: Your convert function calls `Main()` again, that's why it is shown twice

Comment: What you actually need is a `do-while loop`

Comment: @chiapa No. even if the recursion looks strange, it doesn't make bugs in this case. (except stackoverflow if we uses this program lots and lots >o<)

Comment: Wow, so many mistakes in one short program... Get rid of those `return main()` statements to begin with. If you want to repeat the process after the user has entered Y, then just use a simple loop.

Comment: Recursively calling `main` [is allowed in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547777/is-this-code-valid-under-any-c-standard/11547851#11547851) ... but ... *why*? Even the dreaded `goto` would make more sense. There are some *serious* flow problems in this code -- even if it works (which I dare not guarantee, just by looking at it), this shows the OP *seriously* needs consider re-reading on proper use of functions, `do-while` and `while` loops, and flow control in general.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `scanf` leaves `\n` in input buffer. Actually, you input two characters: `y` and `\n`. `scanf` doesn't erase whitespace. (for example: [Simple dump program](http://ideone.com/PiSiXW))

To clear whitespace, you can make `scanf` do that.

```
scanf(" %c",&ia);
/*     ^                 */
/* additional whitespace */
```

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf),

> any single whitespace character in the format string consumes all available consecutive whitespace characters from the input

So the additional whitespace eats `'\n'` and other whitespaces in input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it working and I've posted my answer below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

char y, n, Y, N, ans;
printf("\nWould you like to continue ?:\t");
scanf(" %c",&ans);


switch (ans)
{
case 'y':
case 'Y':
       convert();
break;
case 'N':
case 'n':
       return(0);
break;
default:
    {
        return (0);
    }
break;
return 0;
}

while (ans==y || ans==Y);
return main();
}

int convert (){
    float ia,ca;

    printf("\nEnter amount in Ringgit Malaysia : RM ");
    scanf("%f",&ia);

    ca=ia/3.30;

    printf("\nRM %.2f is equals to USD %.2f\n\n\n",ia,ca);

 return main();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a decent working version ive come up with. its not 100% perfect.
again im not an expert and use your own judgment on best practices etc. Feedback greatly appreciated as im still learning myself, im not a student, just a free time self learner. The reason i did this to begin with is to see if i could help solve a problem in the process of learning, and maybe learn something for future use.

```
/*
* Name: tomyr
* File: tomyr.c
* Description: Converts $USD to MYR (RM). 
* Author: Steven Medley <smedley76@gmail.com>
* Copyright (c) 2016 Steven Medley.
* This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
* it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
* the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
* (at your option) any later version.
* This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
* but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
* MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
* GNU General Public License for more details.
* You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
* along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
// stdlib.h is NOT needed.
int main()
  {
    float usdol; // used to store input as $USD.CC eg: 1.50 
    float myr = 3.30; // this rate (usd/myr) may not be up to date
    char answer; // stores the answer to continue
    do //Loops until you QUIT saying y or Y to continue
      {
        printf("Enter in USD to convert to MYR (Malasia Ringgit) $");
        scanf("%f", &usdol); //possible FIXME: fgets()?? but for this program as is, scanf works
        printf("$%.2f is equal to RM %.2f\n", usdol, usdol/myr);


        /*
        FIXME: i dont check length of answer and enter key acts as newline
               still expecting an answer to the question.
               can be a "2 birds, 1 stone" type of fix.
        */
        LABEL: printf("would you like to continue? y/Y/n/N: ");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);;

     }  
   while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y'); // see above comment next to "do".
   if (answer == 'n' || answer == 'N')
     {
       return 0;
     }
   else
     { // oops answer wasnt a Yy/Nn, attempt at error handling.
       printf ("That was an invalid answer.\n");
       goto LABEL; //possible FIXME: this works, but there could be a better way?.
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

im not going to share any code because im no expert, but it makes more sense to me to use an IF ELSE statement to handle what you have the switch doing,  let convert() do its only job of converting and return a numeric value to your main function and let the main function be the one to printf("") the results. how you implement it is up to you, ive found it to be much less code and a lot more organized.